# How to remove a GPO setting that used a custom ADM

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I'm trying to deal with some legacy group policies that applied registry settings using ADM files.  I'd like to remove these registry settings and set them up as group policy preferences, but how do I do this if I don't have the original ADM file?

Edit:
Just to clarify: I'm not concerned about removing the registry tattooing on the client, just removing the custom setting from the GPO itself.

Comment: Manually comes to mind, as does an "inverse" policy. Do you know which registry changes it applies, at least?

Comment: Are you saying the GPO's directory (e.g. \\<domain>\SYSVOL\<domain>\Policies\<GUID>\ADM) no longer contains the ADM files used to create the GPO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% on how you mean you don't have the original ADM file. I'm assuming it means you don't have them on a local or central store that you have access to. Apologies if I've picked it up wrongly!

You should be able to get the ADM files back taking a backup of the GPO looking in the DomainSysVol\GPO\ADM folder of the backup and picking up a copy of the ADM file from there or alternatively they should be on SYSVOL

```
\\<domain>\SYSVOL\<domain>\Policies\<Unique ID>\ADM
```

Once you know the registry values that are being set you should be able to remove them using the [Get-GPRegistryValue](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461040.aspx) PowerShell cmdlet. Running something like

```
Remove-GPRegistryValue -Name Test -Key HKCU\Software\Mike\Testing
```

should do the job of removing the entry. I've just done some testing and running the command above changed the entry set by the ADM file back to "Not Configured" for me.

Comment: in terms of powershell dont forget that You need to have the "Turn On Script Execution" policy enabled on every computer affected with wrong reg settings. Im suggesting to use native GPO tool to remove reg entries - GPO - User Config - Prefs - Windwos Settings - Registry - Create new object and set Action to Remove [delete]

Comment: @infografik in this case we're removing the registry based policy setting from the GPO itself and not from the individual machines so we won't need to change the Script Execution Policy on the client workstations.